# Python queues, deque implementation

Tags: python, data-structures

Im looking into queues. It seems that when implemented with a list, queues can face a memory issue, where whenever you dequeue, you end up wasting memory at the head's index since you just move the head pointer one index up. Circular queues can circumvent that.

Now, from what I've read, `collections.deque` is the main implementation of queues as a data structure, and it's implemented with a double ended linked list, so it doesn't face this issue right?

If so, what are the pros n cons with implementing a queue with a linked list?

Comment: En/dequeueing elements from either side is O(1), removing anything in the middle is O(N).

Comment: Last In First Out queues are efficient with lists because they don't need to shift the remaining items on a pop.